# Database insert in PHP returns string not defined and notice about unknown column

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to insert into a database a field called `Id_Obj` and it's a VarChar but when I try to send it I get an error:

> Unknown Column 'Id_Obj4' in 'field List'

The insert looks like this:

```
while($info=mysql_fetch_Array($data))
{
  print "name :".$info['Id']." ";
  $count=$info['Id'];
}

$t = "INSERT INTO Table_Faces(Id_Obj,Num_Sides)VALUES(";
$t = $t."IdObj$count".",".$_GET["ns"];
$t = $t.")";

mysql_query($t);
```

The fields in the database are Id, Id_Obj, Num_Sides.

Comment: Don't insert the `ns` parameter directly from the superglobal; always [sanitize your inputs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Usually when i have query problems i echo the string to see what it looks like.  In this case as sholsinger mentioned you will notice the absence of the single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. You really want to make sure that
   your values are [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
2. You're missing out on your last ")"
   in the query
3. Your strings need to be wrapped in
   quotes, otherwise it thinks you're
   using a table name

Your SQL can be like:

```
$t ="INSERT INTO Table_Faces(Id_Obj,Num_Sides)VALUES('IdObj4','". $_GET["ns"]. "')";
```

Also, just as a side so you know the shortcut:

`$t = $t . " something added";` is the same as `$t .= " something added"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap strings with single quotes in SQL.

```
$ns = intval($_GET('ns')); // This should sanitize $ns enough for the db.
if ($ns > 0)
{
  $t="INSERT INTO Table_Faces(Id_Obj,Num_Sides)VALUES(";
  $t = $t."'IdObj4'".",".$ns . ")";
  mysql_query($t);
}
```

You also forgot the closing parenthesis.

I have modified your code to be more resistant to SQL Injection in a very simple way. If you intend to make the `Id_Obj` a variable as well, you should consider using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string/) to escape the value for use in your SQL statement.

Comment: While I should have mentioned that escaping his values is important, I did answer the question. But thanks for your SQL Injection warning.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a situation where your insert query is so small like this, why you don't use everything in a single line? It saves you from a lot of small problems.. I think **@Mark** solved your problem.